# Как изменить объект внутри массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Есть JSON-массив:

```
{
  "terms": {
    "31": {
      "unified_price": 26803,
      "currency": "rub",
      "flights_baggage": [
        [
          "1PC23",
          "1PC23"
        ],
        [
          "1PC23",
          "1PC23"
        ]
      ],
      "flights_handbags": [
        [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "",
          ""
        ]
      ],
      "url": 3100000,
      "price": "26802.08730964467005076142132"
    }
  }
}
```

В нём есть объект **terms**, где первый элемент имеет название "31". Я хочу изменить его таким образом, чтобы он стал массивом и присвоить значение 31 в качестве значения ключа `gate_id`. Должно выглядеть это примерно так:

```
{
  "terms": {
    {
      "gate_id": 31
      "unified_price": 26803,
      "currency": "rub",
      "flights_baggage": [
        [
          "1PC23",
          "1PC23"
        ],
        [
          "1PC23",
          "1PC23"
        ]
      ],
      "flights_handbags": [
        [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "",
          ""
        ]
      ],
      "url": 3100000,
      "price": "26802.08730964467005076142132"
    }
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь изменить его таким образом:

```
$.map(props.terms, (value, i) => $.extend(value, {gate_id: i}));
```

Но ничего не происходит. Объект остаётся объектом.

Comment: "чтобы он стал массивом" - не `{ terms: { { ... } } }`, a `{ terms: [ { ... } ] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "terms": {
    "31": {
      "unified_price": 26803,
      "currency": "rub",
      "flights_baggage": [
        [
          "1PC23",
          "1PC23"
        ],
        [
          "1PC23",
          "1PC23"
        ]
      ],
      "flights_handbags": [
        [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "",
          ""
        ]
      ],
      "url": 3100000,
      "price": "26802.08730964467005076142132"
    }
  }
};

var key = Object.keys(data.terms)[0];
data.terms[key].gate_id = +key;
data.terms = [data.terms[key]];

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо. А почему это не работает с `$.map`?

Comment: И, кстати, попробовал сейчас пустить это через цикл немного переделав и что-то ничего не получилось. `Cannot read property '31' of undefined`

Comment: как Вы с помощью `map` собираетесь превратить `data.terms` в массив? "ничего не получилось" - значит неправильно "переделали". Я должен угадать, как и что Вы "переделали"?

Comment: Абсолютно тот же код, только вместо `data` другая переменная `props[i]` - `let key = Object.keys(props[i].terms)[0];
                props[i].terms[key].gate_id = +key;
                props[i].terms = [data.terms[key]]; // тут ошибка`

Comment: замените `[data.terms[key]]` -> `[props[i].terms[key]]`

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз.